# Why is the linux system call interface architecture-dependent?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

So one thing I'm not clear on is why transitioning from user space to kernel space is architecture-dependent. For example, [the linux kernel v5.4 code for system calls entering kernel space](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S) is different for x86 vs different architectures, and contains architecture-dependent assembly instructions, rather than just C code.

Why is this exactly? Why can't the entire linux kernel just be written in C...?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kernel mode](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/user-mode-and-kernel-mode-switching/) is very different from user-mode. The kernel gets to do anything it wants / access any part of the hardware, but user space is not. How code tells the hardware to switch between modes is specific to the architecture - so that switching mechanism is implemented as machine code - but encapsulated in a C library. You'll find the same thing anywhere that the OS interfaces with the hardware - i.e. in device drivers.

C is meant to be a language for writing operating systems in and providing portability across architectures.

Comment: Different architectures have different privilege modes (e.g., 4 for x86_64, 7 for arm, 3 for risc-v, etc.). Thus different code for different architectures. What your answer didn't address is why entering these modes needs to be done in assembly. `gcc` has compile options to generate instructions entering privileged modes.

Comment: IMHO, the [Lion's Commentary](https://www.amazon.com/Lions-Commentary-Unix-John/dp/1573980137) should be required reading for anybody interested in kernel design. Dated but understandable. Not 28M lines of codes.